# Using UUIDs for related items in Laravel controller actions

Tags: php, laravel, uuid

I have an API built with Laravel, and I'm using UUIDs for external identifiers, alongside autoincrementing integers for internal IDs. I'm using the [laravel-model-uuid](https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-model-uuid) package to make this simpler. For primary lookups, that works great, so I can use paths like `/posts/ed46dbaa-de4d-469f-887a-6e2f90d1fb64`. What's slightly more fiddly is dealing with related records and rendering responses. Say I want to POST to a `/posts` endpoint to create a new post that is linked to a user account, I need to use an internal ID:

```
{
    "title": "My article",
    "user_id": 1,
    "body": "My article text"
}
```

However, I want to use UUIDs instead of internal IDs, like this:

```
{
    "title": "My article",
    "user_uuid": "91e6a4a1-2469-43e4-a3e5-4ddf395eeace",
    "body": "My article text"
}
```

The problem now is that the `posts` model has a `user_id` property, but not a `user_uuid`, so I need to provide an internal lookup and substitute the param in the request:

```
$user_uuid = $request->input('user_uuid');
if ($user_uuid !== null) {
    $user_id = User::whereUuid($user_uuid)->first()->id;
    $request->request->add(['user_id' => $user_id]);
    $request->request->remove('user_uuid');
}
```

Similarly, when rendering a `posts` response, I need to do the reverse in a `posts` resource:

```
$rel['user'] = [
    'data' => [
        'type' => 'users',
        'id'   => $this->user->uuid,
    ],
];
```

This obviously incurs a DB lookup which can become a problem with collections (e.g. when requesting `/posts`) as it causes a query explosion, so I then need to do this to bundle responses:

```
public function index()
{
    return new PostCollection(Post::with('user')->paginate());
}
```

All the above applies to the public API - but that's not all there is: I use Laravel Nova, which has privileged access to all this, and so uses the internal IDs for linking and not the UUIDs. That means my controller methods need to handle both `user_id` *and* `user_uuid` params.

So all this works, but it strikes me as really ugly. Is there a better way?

Comment: yes, ditch the `user_id` and use only `user_uuid`

Comment: That's not really viable - it incurs at least a 400% overhead, and internal IDs do not need defence against enumeration.

Comment: Then use only the `user_id`, you dont need defense against enumeration if you have good middleware and use relations were it is needed.

Comment: @Syncrho I struggle with the same things and have no solution... (i didn't replace the id with the uuid in my case and just hide the real id with `protected $hidden = ['id']`, thats a little bit clearer to me as id is always the internal id)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the keys Laravel uses for relations. Taken from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key');

return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Just tell Laravel to use your UUID instead of the default `id` in your relations.

Comment: I know that, but it's very inefficient, and really doesn't play well with Nova.

Comment: I worked around similar issues by defining multiple relations, one for my code (in your case with UUID) and one or more for Nova with specific use cases.